# Word Cloud from a character string

Tags: r, visualization

I'm trying to make my first word cloud and am a little overwhelmed by something I thought would be simple. I have a vector of strings of text and would like to make a word cloud from them. I would like 2 approaches:
(1) just mush all of the strings together with paste(x, collapse= " ")
and also (although this is lower priority)
(2) I don't want one string to dominate the others so I would like to have its unique words only have weight one. For example, if one string has the same word many times, I would still like that just to count as one.

I've looked at the `tm` and `wordcloud` packages but they all seem designed for more complicated tasks. I can't figure out how to construct a `Corpus` object out of my data.

How can I get started? Here is an example vector in case it helps:

```
example <- c("this is a string of text", "another string of text", "one more string of text. This could be a few sentences long", "it looks like string is occurring a lot of times", "I hope this example is long enough. If not I can write more sentences")
```

Comment: ah, the way to create a Corpus from a vector is `Corpus(VectorSource(example))`. This solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

the way to create a Corpus from a vector is `Corpus(VectorSource(example))`. This solved my problem